# Evis plugin Icon does not show up on the QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have installed evis plugin on my QGIS. Unfortunately, it's Icon is not showing up and it is not in the plugin list.

Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question is expected to provide more detail about your software version, operating systems, and the exact steps you took to get where you are right now.

Comment: I have this problem too.  I am on a Mac and using QGIS 3.0.3.  In version 3 evis is 'builtin'.  There is a known bug on the Mac that the checkbox in the plugin manager is non functional ( there is a bug report for this) so I can't tell if is enabled or not.  Does one need to check built in plugins to enable them?

Answer (score 4):

The plugin may be unchecked in the plugin manager:

[image]

You need to check it and you will find it under Database main menu:

[image]

If you want to see it in the toolbar as as icon, then right-click the main menu toolbar -> activate Database and a new toolbar will be shown and evis will be there:

[image]

[image]